# useState is not updating the state in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chatbot

This is my code. The messages sent by the user are only visible till I get a response from API. Once I get response from user, it dissappears. I tried using useEffect but it is not working. In this code, I am taking input from user in form of query and that query is first given to messages array where all message objects are stored then that message is passed to an API to a response. This response is store in messages which is used to render the messages component and in chat history component which is requirement of API. Chat history is getting updated properly but messages are not. Only messages that I get from API are visible. What am I doing wrong here?

````
import {
  MainContainer,
  ChatContainer,
  MessageList,
  Message,
  MessageInput,
  TypingIndicator
} from "@chatscope/chat-ui-kit-react";

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm";

const ChatBot = () => {

    const [messages , setMessages] = useState([
        {
            message: "Hello",
            sender: "assistant",
            direction: "incoming"
        },
    ]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(messages);
    },[messages]);

    
    const [typing, setTyping] = useState(false);
    const [chatHistory, setChatHistory] = useState([]);

    const HandleSend = async(message) => {
        const newMessage = {
            message : message,
            sender: "user",
            direction: "outgoing"
        }

        setMessages(messages => ([...messages, newMessage]));        


        setTyping(true);

        await processMessageToAPI(message);
    }

    async function processMessageToAPI(messageToBeSent){
        
        const postData = {
            query: messageToBeSent,
            hist: chatHistory
        }

        axios.post("someurl", postData,{
            headers:{
                some headers
            }
        }).then(res => {
            const newResponse = {
                message : res.data[0].Response,
                sender: "assistant",
                direction: "incoming"
            }

            
            const newResponses = [...messages, newResponse];
            
            setMessages(newResponses);

            const newChat = {
                "question": messageToBeSent,
                "answer": res.data[0].Response
            }

            const newHistory = [...chatHistory, newChat];

            setChatHistory(newHistory);

            setTyping(false);

        }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
    }

    return(
        <>
        <MainContainer>
            <ChatContainer>
                <MessageList typingIndicator={typing ? <TypingIndicator content="Assitant is Typing..."/> : null}>
                    {messages.map((message,i)=>{
                        return (
                        <Message key={i} style={{height:"auto"}} model={
                            {
                                type:"custom", 
                                sender: message.sender,
                                direction: message.direction
                            }}>
                            <Message.CustomContent>
                                <ReactMarkdown remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]}>
                                    {message.message}
                                </ReactMarkdown>
                            </Message.CustomContent>
                        </Message>)
                    })}
                </MessageList>
                <MessageInput placeholder="Type your query here..." onSend={HandleSend} attachButton="false"/>
            </ChatContainer>
        </MainContainer>
        </>
    )
}

export default ChatBot;```
````

Comment: The second call to setMessages also needs to use the "function" format like the first call, so it doesn't remove the changes from the first call!

Answer (score 0):

This is totally normal,

You are awaiting your `async function processMessageToAPI` , this function calls `useState` inside it. So basically when resolved it resolves `HandleSend` contains both `setTyping(true)` and `setTyping(false)`. React will batch those two into `setTyping(false)`.

I would suggest to use `setTyping(true)` inside an `onChange` for your `MessageInput` component.